# Best way to parse this in Rebol

Tags: parsing, rebol

How do I extract the transaction receipt datetime with the least bit of noise in my parse rule from the following HTML? (The output I'm looking to get is this: **"Transaction Receipt: 04/28/2011 17:03:09"**)

```
 <FONT COLOR=DARKBLUE>Transaction Receipt </FONT></TH></TR><TR></TR><TR></TR><TR><TD COLSPAN=4 ALIGN=CENTER><FONT SIZE=-1 COLOR=DARKBLUE>04/28/2011 17:03:09</FONT>
```

The following works but I don't get a good feeling! There is guaranteed to be a datetime following the words Transaction Receipt somewhere (although I wouldn't do a greedy match if I'm doing a grep)

```
parse d [
    thru {<FONT COLOR=DARKBLUE>Transaction Receipt </FONT></TH></TR><TR></TR><TR></TR><TR><TD COLSPAN=4 ALIGN=CENTER><FONT SIZE=-1 COLOR=DARKBLUE>}
    copy t to "</FONT>"
    ]
```

Comment: Please repost your code in your question and use the `{}` button to make it code-formatted.

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter...

```
parse d [thru <FONT SIZE=-1 COLOR=DARKBLUE> copy t to </FONT>]
```

but isn't specifically looking for the datetime pair. And unfortunately REBOL considers the date used an invalid one...

```
>> 04/28/2011
** Syntax Error: Invalid date -- 04/28/2011
** Near: (line 1) 04/28/2011
```

so you can't search for it specifically. If the date was 28/04/2011 (and there was a space after the time, though why it's needed for load I'm not sure), the following would work...

```
parse load d [to date! copy t to </FONT>]
```

Hmmm. Try this...

```
t: ""
parse d [
    some [
        to "<" thru ">" mark: copy text to "<" (if text [append t text]) :mark
    ]
]
```

That returns: "Transaction Receipt 04/28/2011 17:03:09"

It works by skipping all the tags, appending any text that's left to t.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well actually that last code returns FALSE, t holding what you want.

Comment: Thanks Carl! Terribly sorry but I think I missed out an important bit of information while phrasing my question -- the HTML I pasted above is actually just a snippet from a much larger document!

Answer (score 1):

Timely as per usual: if the format is consistent, you can always try to explicitly match dates:

```
rule: use [dg tag date value][
    tag: use [chars][
        chars: charset [#"a" - #"z" #"A" - #"Z" #"0" - #"9" " =-"]
        ["<" opt "/" some chars ">"]
    ]

    date: use [dg mo dy yr tm][
        dg: charset "0123456789"
        [
            copy mo [2 dg "/"] copy dy [2 dg "/"] copy yr 4 dg
            " " copy tm [2 dg ":" 2 dg ":" 2 dg]
            (value: load rejoin [dy mo yr "/" tm])
        ]
    ]

    [
        some [
              "Transaction Receipt" (probe "Transaction Receipt")
            | date (probe value)

            ; everything else
            | some " " | tag ; | skip ; will parse the whole doc...
        ]
    ]
]
```